# Cant access a fucntion in flutter

Tags: flutter

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../models/user.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class HomeMaterial extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeMaterialState createState() => _HomeMaterialState();
}

class _HomeMaterialState extends State<HomeMaterial> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _user = User();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Profile')),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
            padding:
                const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0, horizontal: 16.0),
            child: Builder(
                builder: (context) => Form(
                    key: _formKey,
                    child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                        children: [
                          TextFormField(
                            decoration:
                                InputDecoration(labelText: 'First name'),
                            validator: (value) {
                              if (value.isEmpty) {
                                return 'Please enter your first name';
                              }
                            },
                            onSaved: (val) =>
                                setState(() => _user.firstName = val),
                          ),
                          TextFormField(
                              decoration:
                                  InputDecoration(labelText: 'Last name'),
                              validator: (value) {
                                if (value.isEmpty) {
                                  return 'Please enter your last name.';
                                }
                              },
                              onSaved: (val) =>
                                  setState(() => _user.lastName = val)),
                          TextFormField(
                              decoration:
                              InputDecoration(labelText: 'Linkedin Email'),
                              validator: (value) {
                                if (value.isEmpty) {
                                  return 'Please enter your Linkedin Email.';
                                }
                              },
                              onSaved: (val) =>
                                  setState(() => _user.linkedinEmail = val)),
                          Container(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  vertical: 16.0, horizontal: 16.0),
                              child: RaisedButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    print("hi");
                                    _save();
                                    print(_read());
                                    final form = _formKey.currentState;
                                    if (form.validate()) {
                                      form.save();
                                      _user.save();
                                      _showDialog(context);
                                    }
                                  },
                                  child: Text('Save'))),
                        ])))));
  }

  _showDialog(BuildContext context) {
    Scaffold.of(context)
        .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Submitting form')));
  }

  _save() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    // write
    print("reading from stored data");
    prefs.setStringList('my_string_list_key', [_user.firstName,_user.lastName,_user.linkedinEmail]);
  }

  _read() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    // read
    final myStringList = prefs.getStringList('my_string_list_key') ?? [];
  }
}
```

The `_save` function and `_read` function are not being accessed. Could someone tell me why? I am a beginner in flutter.

I am trying to save the user inputted data locally. And later access it in another page. Hence I am using shared preferances

Comment: Is there any error in debug console??

Comment: can you share the error?

Comment: You call async function _save and next _read, I think _save do not keep up to save data. Try call _save().then(() { code after _save})

Comment: there is no error in debug console

Comment: there is an error Class 'Future<dynamic>' has no instance method 'call'.

_save.then worked. but now the read function is not working. help